# Adding two dates to eachother

Tags: c#, datetime

```
string final = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Parse(date, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + TimeSpan.Parse(duration));
```

Hi, I use the above code to **add two date's to eachother**. It do work very well on Windows and returns the required format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` in a correct fashion. HOWEVER, when on Linux building with Mono it returns the following format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` which is not what I want.

How can I specify that I ONLY want the first formatting and nothing else? I tried playing around with ParseExact but it did not do very well. What I've heard ParseExact should not really be needed for this?

**Here is a example of input:**

```
string date = "2014-10-30 10:00:04"; // On windows

string duration = "05:02:10"; // duration to be added to date
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [`Convert.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9e5b1z(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string date = "2014-10-30 10:00:04";  
string duration = "05:02:10";  
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(duration, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dtFinal = dt1.Add(ts);
string final = dtFinal.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[`Convert.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9e5b1z(v=vs.110).aspx) uses your current culture's date separator, use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx).

Read: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ToString() Method of the DateTime object.

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code:

```
string _final = (DateTime.Parse(date, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + TimeSpan.Parse(duration)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```